# iOS Navigation Item issues of extra padding top on landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, navigationitem

There is extra padding top when my app in landscape.
Here is my code when create navigation bar programmatically.
Any advice to remove the padding top when in landscape mode?

```
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)

    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;

    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"

    let btnLeft = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
    btnLeft.setImage(UIImage(named: “myImage.png"), forState: .Normal)

    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem()
    leftButton.customView = btnLeft

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton

    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Snapshot from simulator (Landscape)

[image]

Snapshot from simulator (Portrait)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should easily solve with this setting (in your `viewDidLoad` for example):

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

Alternative: You can put it also in your `UINavigationController` delegate method (if you have setted in your class your navigation delegate `UINavigationControllerDelegate` ) called [willShowViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:):

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
}
```

If you work with `UITableView` you may also to do:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

You can also edit directly to the attribute inspector:

[image]

If anyone of these approaches don't work, by default your `UINavigationBar`  have different heights based on your orientation. For example, the navigation bar is 44 points in portrait and 32 points in landscape.
A workaround can be:

```
// Create an IBOutlet of your navigationBar height constraint
@IBOutlet weak var navBarHeight: NSLayoutConstraint

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        if self.view.bounds.size.height > self.view.bounds.size.width {
            self.navBarHeight.constant = 44
        } else {
            self.navBarHeight.constant = 32
        }
}
```

Comment: No. mine is UIViewController

Comment: do u have any suggestion how to have fix navigation bar 44px both portrait & landscape. From the both snapshot the navigation bar has same height but the navigation button not align middle when in landscape. It appear align much bottom.

Comment: It depend only by constraints. Probably you must review all the navigation elements constraint: reset all, fix manual the nav bar height and do the rest in automatic constraint setting.